# How to connect an item of an array with another item of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have two array:

```
let array1 = ["aaa","bbb"];
let array2 = ["f1","f2","f3"];
```

How can I get the following result?

```
aaa f1, aaa f2, aaa f3, bbb f1, bbb f2, bbb f3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

```js
let array1 = ["aaa", "bbb"];
let array2 = ["f1", "f2", "f3"];

const newArray = [];

array1.forEach(item1 => {
 array2.forEach(item2 => {
  newArray.push(item1 + " " + item2)
 })
})

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const array1 = ["aaa","bbb"];
const array2 = ["f1","f2","f3"];

const result = array1.flatMap(v1 => array2.map(v2 => `${v1} ${v2}`));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let array1 = ["aaa", "bbb" ];
let array2 = ["f1","f2","f3"];
let response=[];
array1.forEach( ele1 => {
 array2.forEach( ele2=> {
   response.push( ele1 +' '+ ele2 );
 })
});
console.log( response );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
let array1 = ["aaa","bbb"];
let array2 = ["f1","f2","f3"];

let res = [];

array1.forEach( a1 => array2.forEach(a2 => res.push([`${a1} ${a2}`])) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1 = ["aaa","bbb"];
let array2 = ["f1","f2","f3"];
let array3 = []
for (ele1 of array1) {
    for (ele2 of array2) {
        array3.push(ele1 + ' ' + ele2);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve required result by using with [Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Please check below code snippet:

```js
let array1 = ["aaa","bbb"],
    array2 = ["f1","f2","f3"];
    
 let result = array1.reduce((r,v)=>[...r,array2.map(m=>`${v} ${m}`).join(',')],[])

console.log(result.join(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

With Loop

```
let array1 = ["aaa","bbb"];
let array2 = ["f1","f2","f3"];

let temp =[];
let index=0;
for(let i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
  for(let j=0;j<array2.length;j++) {
    temp[index] = `${array1[i]} ${array2[j]}`;
    index++;
  }
}

console.log(temp);
```

With For Each

```
    array1.forEach(item1 => {
    array2.forEach(item2 => {
        tempNew.push(item1 + " " + item2)
    })
 })

 console.log(tempNew);
```

JSFiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ou1znbah/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Code:

```js
const array1 = ["aaa", "bbb"];
const array2 = ["f1", "f2", "f3"];

const result = array1.reduce((a, c) => [...a, ...array2.map(f => `${c} ${f}`)], []);

console.log(result);
```